# Implementing voting system struts, mysql

Tags: struts

I'm trying to implement this system: http://en.pudn.com/downloads108/sourcecode/java/jsp/detail446536_en.html

but i get 404 error on login. I enter the url: localhost:8080/voting/.
After entering user and password, correctly, i submit the form and got 404 error :

```
http://localhost:8080/voting/login.html?method=login


HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource () is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.29
```

I configured correctly the DB. 
I don't understand what's the problem?
Please, anybody can help?

there is the struts-config.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.2//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_2.dtd">

<struts-config>
<data-sources>
<data-source type="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
<set-property property="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vote"/>
<set-property property="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<set-property property="username" value="root"/>
<set-property property="password" value="123"/>
<set-property property="maxCount" value="50" />
<set-property property="minCount"  value="30" />
<set-property property="maxActive" value="10" />
<set-property property="maxWait"  value="5000" />
<set-property property="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
</data-source>
</data-sources>
<form-beans >
<form-bean name="loginForm" type="edu.school.voting.control.LoginForm" />
<form-bean name="votesForm" type="edu.school.voting.control.VotesForm" />
<form-bean name="optionsForm" type="edu.school.voting.control.OptionsForm" />

</form-beans>

<global-exceptions />
<global-forwards />
<action-mappings >
 <action
  attribute="loginForm"
  input="/login.jsp"
  name="loginForm"
  parameter="method"
  path="/login"
  scope="request"
  type="edu.school.voting.control.LoginAction">
  <forward name="success" path="/votes.jsp" contextRelative="true" />
  <forward name="admin" path="/admin/admin.jsp" />
  <forward name="error" path="/error.jsp" />
  <forward name="input" path="/login.jsp" />
  <forward name="showuser" path="/admin/user/showuser.jsp" />
  <forward name="amenduser" path="/admin/user/edituser.jsp" />
  <forward name="findusers" path="/login.html?method=list" />
  <forward name="createuser" path="/admin/user/adduser.jsp" />
  </action>
  ......................................
```

Code from login.jsp:

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/login.html?method=login">
            <table width="240" height="165" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle"><table width="230" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="p1">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="45" align="right">ID:</td>
                    <td width="165"><input class="inputPSW"  name="account" id="account" type="text" maxlength="16"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="right">Password:</td>
                    <td><input class="inputPSW" id="pwd" name="pwd"  type="password"  maxlength="16"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <img onClick="return CheckForm();"  src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/login/bn_login1.gif" id="Image1" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image1','','<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/login/bn_login2.gif',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">&nbsp; 
                    <img onClick="return resetBt();" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/login/bn_reset1.gif" id="Image2" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image2','','<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/login/bn_reset2.gif',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
                      <input name="CheckLogin" type="hidden" id="CheckLogin" value="True">                        </td>
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </form>
```

This is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.4" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<servlet>
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>config</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>debug</param-name>
  <param-value>3</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>detail</param-name>
  <param-value>3</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <filter>
<filter-name>encoding</filter-name>
<filter-class>edu.school.voting.common.EncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>encoding</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
<filter-name>safty</filter-name>
<filter-class>edu.school.voting.common.SaftyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>safty</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/admins/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Where am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Not sure how to help; what's in the logs? What's the code? Config? Etc.

Comment: i hoped to find someone who had tried this application before because it's important to try it yourself to understand the problem...

Comment: This might have been caused due to wrong configurations. Error http 404 means resource or method is not available. Show some snippets of your configurations, that will be help understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're actually mapping your action servlet to `*.html`, the `"action"` attribute in your form tag is almost certainly wrong. If you're using a dispatch action, the action should point to the action configured in your `struts-config` file.

That aside, why aren't you using any of the Struts 1 form tags? They make things much easier. Also, I'd recommend putting your JSP files under `WEB-INF` so they can't be accessed directly by a client.

Also, this has nothing to do with Spring MVC, Hibernate, or Struts 2.

Comment: I need to make this application works. No matter which framework it's using. What you suggest me to do to fix it?

Comment: @rakela You are not providing information with which to diagnose the problem. 404? You're trying to access a resource that doesn't exist. I don't know what your action mapping is. The tags are for adding metadata to the post regarding what technologies are used--if you're using Struts 1, which by every indication you are, tagging it with anything else other than Struts 1 is bizarre.